# sql query using aggregate function inside case

Tags: sql, join, case, aggregate-functions, mariadb

I'm trying to solve #13 on http://www.sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

"List every match with the goals scored by each team as shown. This will use "CASE WHEN" which has not been explained in any previous exercises."

Here is what I wrote:

```
select distinct mdate, team1,
 case 
    when teamid = team1
      count(teamid)
 end as score1, team2,
 case 
    when teamid = team2
     count(teamid) 
 end as score2
from game join goal on id = matchid
group by matchid
order by mdate, matchid, team1, team2;
```

I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(teamid) end as score1, team2, case when teamid = tea' at line 4

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your syntax error is because you are missing the `then` keyword in the `case` statement. but even if you fix that, this query will not provide the results expected by the exercise.

Comment: please tell me why??

Comment: The `COUNT(teamid)` is computed on the entire table, then the `CASE` decides whether to use it or not.  ("not" if the `WHEN` fails`.)

Comment: So you mean that in this case count() will count all rows in the table even if i use group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you r on wrong track with case condition and using functions..below query give you result..check and learn hope it will help

```
SELECT  game.mdate, 
        game.team1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid=game.team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1, 
        game.team2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid=game.team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
FROM game
INNER JOIN goal 
    ON game.id=goal.matchid
GROUP BY game.mdate, goal.matchid, game.team1, game.team2
```

Comment: So you mean that we cant use aggregate function inside case??

Comment: @RadhikaMathur we can use..no pbs..but for this we dont want to use it..here case should come inside sum then only it wwill sum 1 according to the team case as above..please study the query given above.